# Why the program does not give me the minimum value of an array?

Tags: java, arrays, min

```
public static int n = 10;
public static int i = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = new int[n];
    int max = arr[i];
    int min = arr[i];
    FullArr(arr);
    MinArr(arr);
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (max < arr[i]) {
            max = arr[i];
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(max);
    }
}

public static void FullArr(int[] ar) {
    int[] arr = new int[n];
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        ar[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
        System.out.print(ar[i] + ", ");
    }
}

public static void MinArr(int[] ar) {
    int min = ar[i];
    for (i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
        if (min > ar[i]) {
            min = ar[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(min);
}
```

The program gives me the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
    at home.ifif.MinArr(ifif.java:35)
    at home.ifif.main(ifif.java:12)
```

Comment: Check the value of 'i'

Comment: Why is `i` a static member of your class? And you are you initializing `min` with `ar[i]` and not `ar[0]`?

Comment: your i variable is global to the functions.

Comment: I think your first line of `MinArr` should be `int min = ar[0]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line of your MinArr function is

```
int min = ar[i];
```

But at that point i still has the value from after the last for loop in FullArr. For that reason, i should not be a property of your class but a local variable for each of your functions. So remove the line that declare i as a property. The lines that declare min and max should be

```
int min = arr[0]
```

and

```
int max = arr[0]
```

And i should be a variable local to your for loops, so the loops should start with `for(int i = 0;...`

The complete program would look something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = new int[10];
    int max = arr[0];
    int min = arr[0];
    FullArr(arr);
    MinArr(arr);
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (max < arr[i]) {
            max = arr[i];
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(max);
    }
}

public static void FullArr(int[] ar) {
    int[] arr = new int[ar.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        ar[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
        System.out.print(ar[i] + ", ");
    }
}

public static void MinArr(int[] ar) {
    int min = ar[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
        if (min > ar[i]) {
            min = ar[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(min);
}
```